# Laravel can't get user image

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem. I want to get user image link from DB but I'm getting nothing. Just blank space. I don't know why this is happening because other attributes are showing. Heres the code:

**forum.integration.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application user model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The user model from the main application
|
*/

'user_model' => 'App\User',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application user name attribute
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The attribute on the user model to use as a display name.
|
*/

'user_name_attribute' => 'name',
'user_role_attribute' => 'role',
'user_image_attribute' => 'image',
```

**HasAuthor.php**

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(config('forum.integration.user_model'), 'author_id');
}

public function getAuthorNameAttribute()
{
    $attribute = config('forum.integration.user_name_attribute');

    if (!is_null($this->author) && isset($this->author->$attribute)) {
        return $this->author->$attribute;
    }

    return NULL;
}

public function getAuthorRoleAttribute()
{
    $attribute = config('forum.integration.user_role_attribute');

    return $this->author->$attribute;
}

public function getAuthorImageAttribute()
{
    $attribute = config('forum.integration.user_image_attribute');

    return $this->author->attribute;
}
```

I'm getting this fine -> `$post->authorRole`

Also I'm getting this fine -> `$post->authorName`

But when I do `$post->authorImage` I get nothing. No errors, just blank space.

Comment: If you `dd($post->authorImage)` what was the result? `Null` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting `Null`

Comment: Are you sure, there is an image in your database that you try to query?

Comment: Yes, image is showing in user profile, also there is a link in database

Comment: I fixed it! I didn't add the `&` sign before attribute!
 return $this->author-> `$` attribute;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is missing a `$`. It should be like this:

```
public function getAuthorImageAttribute()
{
    $attribute = config('forum.integration.user_image_attribute');

    return $this->author->$attribute;
}
```

Note the extra `$` before `attribute` in the last line.

Comment: Lol we posted at the same time! I checked your answer!

Comment: Yep, noticed it too :)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add `$` sign to this line:

```
public function getAuthorImageAttribute()
{
    $attribute = config('forum.integration.user_image_attribute');

    return $this->author->**$**attribute;
}
```